# mitigating ssl bypassing on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, cydia-substrate

I am trying to mitigate ssl bypassing on a jailbroken iOS.
I am unable to find any good work around as mobile substrate and SSL kill switch are able to bypass SSL.

I have tried two things:

- SSL Pinning
- Detect jailbreak and stop the application

Both can be cracked. My application handles confidential data so securing from SSL kill switch and mobile substrate is necessary. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Here is my theory on why you may not have to worry too much.  The thing with SSL Kill switch is it only works on the current device it is installed on.  So it only can snoop information from that single user, the hacker already has info to that account anyways.  What he does have is how your server works, but in real life, you should not be vulnerable if people knows all your endpoints and query formats.

Comment: I also want to know if you have found a solution to your problem, and what it was.

Comment: I was trying to hide the data i wanted to transmit as it was critical so instead,  added a PKI infrastructure to my app. This way i can terminate access to my server for any unauthorized user. currently working on another task so will return to this part after some time

Comment: What makes you think that cannot be hacked?

Comment: i am assuming that it is hacked, and the hacker has everything. Thats is why i am building such code that my server side is safe regardless of the client side for now. Using PKI the recovery options are good and widely tested. Currently making server side changes so will  get back to mobile applications after some time p.s. I am following the OWASP project as a benchmark. If you have any suggestion, i'll be glad to hear